# How to average each value in two separate sheets in excel into a third sheet

Tags: excel, average, xlsx

Say I have an excel file with two sheets:

```
Sheet 1
    2    2    2
    4    4    4
Sheet 2
    0    0    0
    2    2    2
```

How would I take the average of each individual value from sheets 1 and 2 respecting their positions to produce a third sheet with averaged values like so?

```
Sheet 3
    1    1    1
    3    3    3
```

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/hide-multiple-tabs-excel-2007-39960.html) but that only produces one value in one cell for me. It appears to be taking the average of every number across two sheets and giving back one number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AVERAGE with a 3d reference:

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet1:Sheet2!A1)
```

Note that Sheet1 and Sheet2 need to be next to each other and in that order.

[image]

If the sheets are not next to each other then:

```
=AVERAGE(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1)
```

Comment: Those worked! Can you explain what the '!A1' means? –

Comment: The is typical nomenclature to separate the name of sheet from the range reference.  `Sheet1!A1` means cell `A1` on `Sheet1`

Comment: .... *hmmm, wonders if one can use a 3D reference with BYROW, BYCOL, MAP, etc.*

Comment: Is there a better way to do this other than to specify A1 then drag the formula box down and across? Can you specify the range of rows and columns ahead of time so it will automatically average the entire 2x3 grid at once?

Comment: @Barry that depends on which version of excel you are using

Comment: I am using Excel 2016

Comment: Then no, there is not without vba.